# PowerCollections - MultiDictionary 'Remove' removing all values when value not found

Tags: c#, collections

I am using the powercollections library from http://powercollections.codeplex.com/

The first test passes, however the second test fails. I wouldn't expect `Remove` to remove all items from the dictionary if a value was not found.

Is this an issue or am I misunderstanding how `Remove` functions ?

```
[Test]
public void passing_test()
{
    var classes = new MultiDictionary<string, object>(false);
    classes.Add("class", "class_name1");
    classes.Add("class", "class_name2");
    classes.Remove("class", "class_name2");

    Assert.AreEqual(1, classes.Count);
}

[Test]
public void failing_test()
{
    var classes = new MultiDictionary<string, object>(false);
    classes.Add("class", "class_name1");
    classes.Remove("class", "class_name2");

    Assert.AreEqual(1, classes.Count);
}
```

Comment: In your failing test, you have created a new empty dictionary, added 1 item and then removed that item, therefore count should be zero.

Comment: Mitch, I'm removing a different item

Comment: @Michael Wolfenden : first param is the key (i have no idea why Remove requires anything but the key), therefore you are removing the item you just added. Please see answer below....

Comment: Mitch, the MultiDictionary stores multiple values for the same key.

Comment: @Michael Wolfenden: Thx. I realised that after reading the help file!

Comment: That the strangest Q&A I ever almost participated in.  Don't forget to report the bug on the PowerCollections CodePlex Issue Tracker site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually looks like a bug in the code:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Removes a given value from the values associated with a key. If the
        /// last value is removed from a key, the key is removed also.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">A key to remove a value from.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to remove.</param>
        /// <returns>True if <paramref name="value"/> was associated with <paramref name="key"/> (and was
        /// therefore removed). False if <paramref name="value"/> was not associated with <paramref name="key"/>.</returns>
        public sealed override bool Remove(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            KeyAndValues keyValues = new KeyAndValues(key);
            KeyAndValues existing;

            if (hash.Find(keyValues, false, out existing)) {
                // There is an item in the hash table equal to this key. Find the value.
                int existingCount = existing.Count;
                int valueHash = Util.GetHashCode(value, valueEqualityComparer);
                int indexFound = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < existingCount; ++i) {
                    if (Util.GetHashCode(existing.Values[i], valueEqualityComparer) == valueHash &&
                        valueEqualityComparer.Equals(existing.Values[i], value)) 
                    {
                        // Found an equal existing value
                        indexFound = i;
                    }
                }

                if (existingCount == 1) {
                    // Removing the last value. Remove the key.
                    hash.Delete(existing, out keyValues);
                    return true;
                }
```

Notice how they are checking for `existingCount == 1`? Although the values you entered differ, there is no code to check whether the index was found in the search prior to the `hash.Delete` call. The correct way to fix this would be to do something like:

```
            if (existingCount == 1 && indexFound != -1) {
                // Removing the last value. Remove the key.
                hash.Delete(existing, out keyValues);
                return true;
            }
```

Here's the full source: http://powercollections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6259#71508